# How to use same form code for add,update

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

## test.kv

## :kivy 1.10.0

```
<CRUD>:
    title: self.mode + " State"
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 350, 350
    auto_dismiss: False

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Label:
                text: root.label_rec_id
            Label:
                id: userid
                text: root.col_data[0]  # root.userid
            Label:
                text: "First Name"
            TextInput:
                id: fname
                text: root.col_data[1]  # root.fname
            Label:
                text: "Last Name"
            TextInput:
                id: lname
                text: root.col_data[2]  # root.lname
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.4
            text: "Save Changes"
            on_release:
                root.package_changes(fname.text, lname.text)
                app.root.update_changes(root)
                root.dismiss()
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.4
            text: "Cancel Changes"
            on_release: root.dismiss()
```

1. when click on any row then edit form open.Can i use same form for add user.

At this time i click on add user then user.py file run and open a new form.how to use same form for both add update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same form to add city. In the example, I added a button, a method add_record, some variable e.g. mode of type StringProperty, and INSERT SQL command. Please refer to the example for details.

## Example

### main.py

```
import kivy

kivy.require('1.10.0')  # replace with your current kivy version !
import sqlite3 as lite
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.core.window import Window


Window.size = (500, 500)

MAX_TABLE_COLS = 3

con = lite.connect('company.db')
# con.text_factory = str
cur = con.cursor()


class CRUD(Popup):
    """CRUD - Create, Read, Update, Delete"""
    label_id_text = ObjectProperty(None)
    label_id_data = ObjectProperty(None)

    mode = StringProperty("")
    label_rec_id = StringProperty("UserID")
    start_point = NumericProperty(0)
    col_data = ListProperty(["", "", ""])

    def __init__(self, obj, **kwargs):
        super(CRUD, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.mode = obj.mode
        if obj.mode == "Add":
            self.label_id_text.opacity = 0  # invisible
            self.label_id_data.opacity = 0  # invisible
        else:
            self.label_id_text.opacity = 1  # visible
            self.label_id_data.opacity = 1  # visible
            self.start_point = obj.start_point
            self.col_data[0] = obj.rv_data[obj.start_point]["text"]
            self.col_data[1] = obj.rv_data[obj.start_point + 1]["text"]
            self.col_data[2] = obj.rv_data[obj.start_point + 2]["text"]

    def package_changes(self, fname, lname):
        self.col_data[1] = fname
        self.col_data[2] = lname


class SelectableRecycleGridLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                  RecycleGridLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''


class SelectableButton(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Button):
    ''' Add selection support to the Button '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)
    rv_data = ObjectProperty(None)
    start_point = NumericProperty(0)
    mode = StringProperty("")

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableButton, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableButton, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected
        self.rv_data = rv.data

    def on_press(self):
        self.mode = "Update"
        self.start_point = 0
        end_point = MAX_TABLE_COLS
        rows = len(self.rv_data) // MAX_TABLE_COLS
        for row in range(rows):
            if self.index in list(range(end_point)):
                break
            self.start_point += MAX_TABLE_COLS
            end_point += MAX_TABLE_COLS

        popup = CRUD(self)
        popup.open()


class RV(BoxLayout):
    rv_data = ListProperty([])
    start_point = NumericProperty(0)
    mode = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.get_users()

    def get_users(self):
        '''This result retrieve from database'''
        self.rv_data = []

        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY UserID ASC")
        rows = cur.fetchall()

        # create data_items
        for row in rows:
            for col in row:
                self.rv_data.append(col)

    def add_record(self):
        self.mode = "Add"
        popup = CRUD(self)
        popup.open()

    def update_changes(self, obj):
        if obj.mode == "Add":
            # insert record into Database Table
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO Users VALUES(NULL, ?, ?)",
                        (obj.col_data[1], obj.col_data[2]))
        else:
            # update Database Table
            cur.execute("UPDATE Users SET FirstName=?, LastName=? WHERE UserID=?",
                        (obj.col_data[1], obj.col_data[2], obj.col_data[0]))
        con.commit()
        self.get_users()


class ListUser(App):
    title = "Users"

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('main.kv')
        return RV()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ListUser().run()
```

### main.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<CRUD>:
    label_id_text: label_id_text
    label_id_data: label_id_data

    title: self.mode + " State"
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 350, 350
    auto_dismiss: False

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Label:
                id: label_id_text
                text: "ID"
            Label:
                id: label_id_data
                text: root.col_data[0]  # root.userid
            Label:
                text: "First Name"
            TextInput:
                id: fname
                text: root.col_data[1]  # root.fname
            Label:
                text: "Last Name"
            TextInput:
                id: lname
                text: root.col_data[2]  # root.lname
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.4
            text: "Confirm " + root.mode
            on_release:
                root.package_changes(fname.text, lname.text)
                app.root.update_changes(root)
                root.dismiss()
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.4
            text: "Cancel " + root.mode
            on_release: root.dismiss()

<SelectableButton>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if self.selected else (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<RV>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
            text: "Add Record"
            on_press: root.add_record()

        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 25
            cols: 3

            Label:
                text: "ID"
            Label:
                text: "First Name"
            Label:
                text: "Last Name"

        BoxLayout:
            RecycleView:
                viewclass: 'SelectableButton'
                data: [{'text': str(x)} for x in root.rv_data]
                SelectableRecycleGridLayout:
                    cols: 3
                    default_size: None, dp(26)
                    default_size_hint: 1, None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    multiselect: True
                    touch_multiselect: True
```

### Output

[image: Figure 1 - App Startup]
[image: Figure 2 - SQLite3 Database]
[image: Figure 3 - Add Record Joe Plummer]
[image: Figure 4 - RecycleView Data Updated with Joe Plummer]
[image: Figure 5 - SQLite3 Database Updated with Joe Plummer]
[image: Figure 6 - Update John Doe to Jane Doe]
[image: Figure 7 - RecycleView Data Updated with Jane Doe]
[image: Figure 8 - SQLite3 Database Updated with Jane Doe]

Comment: thanks for reply.can you tell me how to use?I am confuse that when I add then how to hide edit value.I am so confusing about this.Can you please tell me how to use same code for add,update.thanks

Comment: Thanks.It's working Please can you tell me one more thing how to hide userId label when I add state.Because its my primary id when i add state then it will be auto increment So no need userId label.

Comment: when add record then self.label_rec_id = " " so showing blank space.Can i remove blank space?

Comment: I have updated my code to use opacity property to hide widgets.